# What do we mean by ? OR ???

Tags: c#, language-features

Someone tell me the difference and example why we use these. I know its for NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two different operator which use '?'

- [Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) Operator: 
  condition?then:else
  if condition is true then 'then part' else 'else part', this operator is like if-else.
- [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator: 
  The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.
  // y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1.
      int y = x ?? -1;

Answer (score 9):

`x ? a : b` means `if (x == true) then a else b`

`x ?? y` means `if (x != null) then x else y`

but with a twist since both are expressions rather than statements like the IF.

That allow you to write `var z = x ? a : b;` to combine declaration and assignment in one line instead of the multi-line alternative:

```
type z;
if (x == true)
  z = a;
else
  z = b;
```

`Type?` is a shorthand for `Nullable<Type>`

Comment: Add the use of `?` to make a value type nullable and you have the trifecta, IMO.

Comment: Type? and ?? are introduced in  c# 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

? is a ternary operator, officially named the conditional operator in C#.

?? is the null coalescing operator

The conditional operator is useful for short, concise if/else statements

The null coalescing operator is useful for returning one value if it is not null, otherwise returning another value (the value on the right side of the operator)

Comment: It is *a* ternary operator. Its given name is the conditional operator.

Comment: You learn something every day :).  I looked it up and you are definitely correct, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) or [Conditional Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

The second one is a [Null Coalescing Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator).